# Expanding all definitions in Isabelle lemma

Tags: expression, isabelle

How can I tell Isabelle to expand all my `definition`s, please, because that way the proof is trivial? Unfortunately there is no default expansion or simplification happens, and basically I get back the original expression as the subgoal.

Example:

```
theory Test
  imports Main

begin
 
definition b0 :: "nat⇒nat"
  where "b0 n ≡ (n mod 2)"

definition b1 :: "nat⇒nat"
  where "b1 n ≡ (n div 2)"

lemma "(a::nat)≤3 ∧ (b::nat)≤3 ⟶
  2*(b1 a)+(b0 a)+2*(b1 b)+(b0 b) = a+b"
  apply auto
  oops

end
```

Respose before `oops`:

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. a ≤ 3 ⟹
    b ≤ 3 ⟹ 2 * b1 a + b0 a + 2 * b1 b + b0 b = a + b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My recommendation: `unfolding`

There is a special keyword `unfolding` for unpacking definitions at the start of proofs. For your example this would read:

```
unfolding b0_def b1_def by simp
```

I consider `unfolding` the most elegant way. It also helps while writing the proofs. Internally, this is (mostly?) equivalent to using the `unfold`-method:

```
apply (unfold b0_def b1_def) by simp
```

This will recursively (!) use the set of equalities you supply to rewrite the proof goal. (Due to the recursion, you should rather not supply a set of equalities that could generate cycles...)

### Alternative: Using the simplifier

In cases with possible loops, the simplifier might be able to reach a nice unfolding without running into these cycles, maybe by interleaving with other simplifications. In such cases, `by (simp add: b0_def b1_def)`, as you've suggested, is great!

### Alternative definition: Maybe it's just an `abbreviation` (and no `definition`)?

If you find yourself unfolding a definition in every single instance, you could consider, using `abbreviation` instead of `definition`. Then, some Isabelle magic will do the packing/unpacking for you without further hints. `abbeviation` does only affect how the user communicates with Isabelle. It does not introduce new symbols at the object level, and consequently, there would be no `b1_def` facts and the like.

```
abbreviation b0 :: "nat⇒nat"
  where "b0 n ≡ (n mod 2)"
```

### Usually not recommended: Building something like an abbreviation using the simplifier

If you (for whatever reason) want to have a defined name at the object level, but unfold it in almost every instance, you can also feed the defining equality directly into the simplifier.

```
definition b0 :: "nat⇒nat"
  where [simp]: "b0 n ≡ (n mod 2)"
```

(Usually there should be little reason for the last option.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I keep forgetting that definitions are not used in simplifications by default.

Adding the definitions explicitly to the simplification rules solves this problem:

```
lemma "(a::nat)≤3 ∧ (b::nat)≤3 ⟶
  2*(b1 a)+(b0 a)+2*(b1 b)+(b0 b) = a+b"
  by (simp add: b0_def b1_def)
```

This way the definitions (`b0`, `b1`) are correctly used.